# CakePHP centralized validation rules

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm currently setting the validate array using the beforeFind() method. The rules are in AppModel and I simply call 'field' => $this->pics to get the rules. I have a lot of models and fields so I can't imagine doing it field per field. Now with my file uploader the beforeFind() won't work but it works the normal way. Can I do a call back to call a rule on AppModel? Or is there another way I can do it before the beforeFind()?

Comment: Why do you want validations for beforeFind? Validations are used in the context of saving data, not finding it.

Comment: Because if not on beforeFind the field labels don't auto indicate a required field and auto bold and then my upload plugin won't validate.

Comment: You might be better off using a Behavior

Comment: Ok but then won't be the same with a behavior? I'll have to set a behavior for each field no? I want to at least be able to handle the validation rules for over 500 fields in a centralized area.

Comment: I just tried setting a custom validation rule and then $this->validator()->add on the field but doesn't work.

Comment: Got it! A behavior will work just fine.